# How did Victor Banerjee do the train scene in A Passage to India?

Tags: stunts, passage-to-india

Victor Banerjee climbs along a train moving across a high bridge. He doesn't appear to be roped on.

There wasn't any CGI at that time. Did he really do these stunts because they seems highly dangerous?

Comment: There is apparently a bit about this in an old Newsnight report. Transcript and screenshots here: http://www.mapability.com/travel/p2i/mtully1.php

Comment: A direct link to the video (taken from the page referenced above): http://news.bbc.co.uk/player/nol/newsid_7270000/newsid_7275100/7275142.stm?bw=bb&mp=rm&news=1&nol_storyid=7275142&bbcws=1#

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y1Y4.jpg / https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPWyI.jpg